# Find matching month between datasets and sequence a multiplication between values in specific rows between the sets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet for a Project P&L with a data sequenced using the following formula where C2 is 01/01/2020 and E2 is the duration of the project at 39 months:

`=EDATE($C$2, SEQUENCE(1, $E$2, 0))`

This gives the following:

[image: Project Costs]

I have another sheet called Studio Costs which has a calculated per person monthly expense as follows:

[image: Per Person Monthly Expense]

For the **Project P&L** sheet I'd like to create a sequenced formula in I9 for **Project Costs** based on the number of months determined by E2(39), such that it compares the date in row 1 with the dates in row 1 of the dataset in the **Studio Costs** sheet, and on finding the matching column, multiply the **Monthly Per Employee Costs** value in row 5 by the **Active Staff** value in row 2 of the **Project P&L** dataset to give the monthly studio costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula to be placed in `I9`:

```
=(I2:P2)*HLOOKUP(I1:P1,'Studio Costs'!$AC$1:$AL$5,5,FALSE)
```

Change ranges as needed.

EDIT: Final solution to use dynamic ranges author came up with:

```
=(I2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(I2),COLUMN(I2)+$E$2-1)))*HLOOKUP(I1:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(I1),COLUMN(I1)+$E$2-1)),'Studio Costs'!$B$1:$KO$5,5,FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi @user11222393 I assume I4 should be I1? Changing to =I2*HLOOKUP(I1,'Studio Costs'!B1#,5,FALSE) I unfortunately receive a Ref error. It also looks like it's only going to fill out the I9 cell. I'd need the formula to auto sequence across row 9 without drag copying cells, similar to how the date is sequenced in cell I1.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it needs to be I1. But your range 'Studio costs'!B1# is not correct. It needs to be from searchable table 1st cell to last one, as in used example 'Studio costs'!$AC$1:$AL$5, where AC1 is top left cell and AL5 is last row to search in. And yes, unfortunately you would need to drag this formula to right cells

Comment: Edited formula. This formula placed in I9 should spill all values to right

Comment: That works @user11222393, however I'd like the ranges I2:P2 and I1:P1 be determined by the value in E2 similar to the way the months are sequenced. Is there a way to modify the formula to do this?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You might need to use ADDRESS, COLUMN, ROW formulas to get the results. I am sure you should find answers in SO on how to add n columns to starting coulmn (in this case I2+39) to get needed range.

Comment: Got it working with the following adjustment, would you mind editing the answer to reflect please =(I2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(I2),COLUMN(I2)+$E$2-1)))*HLOOKUP(I1:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(I1),COLUMN(I1)+$E$2-1)),'Studio Costs'!$B$1:$KO$5,5,FALSE)

Comment: Nicely done. Edited